# Doctrine - return result that is not 0

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-3.4

I am trying to write query where I can check db table on every action trigger and return data if there is just one entity object that is equal or greater than 0.

Can I do it in query or I need to iterate through array?

My try:

```
$query = $this->getMyRepository()
    ->createQueryBuilder('a')
    ->select('COUNT(a)')
    ->where("mod(:units, a.units) >= 0")
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();

if ($query) {
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `$query->getOneOrNullResult();` [doc](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-phpcr-odm/en/latest/reference/query.html#getoneornullresult)

Answer (score 0):

The parsing of a result with select containing a `count` is a bit different than classic queries.

You could try this. Maybe the code can be refactored. It's an old (but working) example.

```
$result = $qb->getQuery()->getScalarResult()[0];

return count($result) !== 0 ? (int) array_shift($result) : 0;
```